# What is the data format returned by the AdWords API TargetingIdeaPage service?

Tags: python, pandas, google-ads-api

When I query the AdWords API to get [search volume data and trends through their TargetingIdeaSelector](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/targeting-idea-service#get_search_volume_data_and_trends) using the [Python client library](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/blob/master/examples/adwords/v201601/optimization/get_keyword_ideas.py) the returned data looks like this:

```
(TargetingIdeaPage){
       totalNumEntries = 1
       entries[] = 
          (TargetingIdea){
             data[] = 
                (Type_AttributeMapEntry){
                   key = "KEYWORD_TEXT"
                   value = 
                      (StringAttribute){
                         Attribute.Type = "StringAttribute"
                         value = "keyword phrase"
                      }
                },
                (Type_AttributeMapEntry){
                   key = "TARGETED_MONTHLY_SEARCHES"
                   value = 
                      (MonthlySearchVolumeAttribute){
                         Attribute.Type = "MonthlySearchVolumeAttribute"
                         value[] = 
                            (MonthlySearchVolume){
                               year = 2016
                               month = 2
                               count = 2900
                            },
                            ...
                            (MonthlySearchVolume){
                               year = 2015
                               month = 3
                               count = 2900
                            },
                      }
                },
          },
     }
```

This isn't JSON and appears to just be a messy Python list. What's the easiest way to flatten the monthly data into a Pandas dataframe with a structure like this?

```
Keyword         |  Year  | Month | Count
 keyword phrase    2016      2       10
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output is a sudsobject. I found that this code does the trick:

```
import suds.sudsobject as sudsobject
import pandas as pd
a = [sudsobject.asdict(x) for x in output]
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
```

> Addendum: This was once correct but new versions of the API (I tested
>   201802) now return a zeep.objects. However, zeep.helpers.serialize_object should do the same trick.
>   [link](http://docs.python-zeep.org/en/latest/helpers.html)

Comment: Sorry for my delay responding! Thanks for explaining! Much simpler code to get this done!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the complete code that I used to query the TargetingIdeaSelector, with requestType STATS, and the method I used to parse the data to a useable dataframe; note the section starting "Parse results to pandas dataframe" as this takes the output given in the question above and converts it to a dataframe. Probably not the fastest or best, but it works! Tested with Python 2.7.

```
"""This code pulls trends for a set of keywords, and parses into a dataframe.

The LoadFromStorage method is pulling credentials and properties from a
"googleads.yaml" file. By default, it looks for this file in your home
directory. For more information, see the "Caching authentication information"
section of our README.

"""

from googleads import adwords
import pandas as pd


adwords_client = adwords.AdWordsClient.LoadFromStorage()

PAGE_SIZE = 10

# Initialize appropriate service.
targeting_idea_service = adwords_client.GetService(
    'TargetingIdeaService', version='v201601')

# Construct selector object and retrieve related keywords.
offset = 0
stats_selector = {
    'searchParameters': [
        {
            'xsi_type': 'RelatedToQuerySearchParameter',
            'queries': ['donald trump', 'bernie sanders']
        },
        {
        # Language setting (optional).
        # The ID can be found in the documentation:
        #  https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/languagecodes
            'xsi_type': 'LanguageSearchParameter',
            'languages': [{'id': '1000'}],
        },
        {
            # Location setting
            'xsi_type': 'LocationSearchParameter',
            'locations': [{'id': '1027363'}]  # Burlington,Vermont
        }
    ],
    'ideaType': 'KEYWORD',
    'requestType': 'STATS',
    'requestedAttributeTypes': ['KEYWORD_TEXT', 'TARGETED_MONTHLY_SEARCHES'],
    'paging': {
        'startIndex': str(offset),
        'numberResults': str(PAGE_SIZE)
    }
}

stats_page = targeting_idea_service.get(stats_selector)


##########################################################################
# Parse results to pandas dataframe


stats_pd = pd.DataFrame()

if 'entries' in stats_page:
    for stats_result in stats_page['entries']:
        stats_attributes = {}
        for stats_attribute in stats_result['data']:
            #print (stats_attribute)
            if stats_attribute['key'] == 'KEYWORD_TEXT':
                kt = stats_attribute['value']['value']
            else:
                for i, val in enumerate(stats_attribute['value'][1]):                
                    data = {'keyword': kt,
                            'year': val['year'],
                            'month': val['month'],
                            'count': val['count']}
                    data = pd.DataFrame(data, index = [i])                
                    stats_pd = stats_pd.append(data, ignore_index=True)


print(stats_pd)
```

Comment: Does this code use credentials generated via a test account? If so, are the results meaningful? Elsewhere I've read that test accounts produce "dummy" data. Thanks- Chris

Comment: I'm using a real account, and the data are certainly meaningful. I can't comment on what happens when you use a test account. That said, it does concern me that you need to use a 'real' account as it's unclear how the account settings may (or may not) influence the results returned.

Comment: Thanks. My understanding is that the test accounts return dummy results because Google restricts access to the real data in order to prevent abuses/violations of the TOS etc.